# realloc() does not copy the data correctly when trying to resize a matrix in c

Tags: c, matrix, realloc

I'm trying to resize a matrix (double **m) in c, in theory realloc() should copy the data of the old matrix to the new resized one. However, the values in the matrix are not or randomly copied to the new version.
The resizing itself works correctly, at least it prints with the right amount of rows and columns.

```
double **matrix_resize(double **m, int rows, int cols) 
{
    int i;
    double **safe;
    safe = realloc(m, rows * sizeof(double*));
    if (safe == NULL) return NULL;
    m = safe;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        double *safe2 = realloc(m[i], cols * sizeof(double));
        if (safe2 == NULL) {
            free(safe2);
            free(safe);
            return NULL;
        }
        m[i] = safe2;
        free(safe2);
    }
    free(safe);
    return m;
}
```

I expected the function to return a new matrix with the new amount of rows and columns, also with the old data copied into the new matrix. The amount of rows and columns is correct, however it does not copy the data correctly.

This is the output:

```
old matrix:

-----0---1---2---
0: | 1 | 1 | 1 |
---------------
1: | 1 | 1 | 1 |
---------------
2: | 1 | 1 | 1 |
---------------

resized matrix:

-----0---1---2---3---4---
0: | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
-------------------------
1: | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
-------------------------
2: | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
-------------------------
3: | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
-------------------------
4: | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
-------------------------
```

Comment: `m[i] = safe2;` followed by `free(safe2);` does not look correct, and `free(safe);` at the end does not look correct. Also, if the number of rows is increased, the additional row pointers will be junk pointer values before they are reallocated, so you need to know the old number of rows to be able to initialize the new ones. (You also need the old number of columns to initialize new columns, but that can be done outside the resize function.)

Comment: You cannot use `realloc` on uninitialized pointers, either `NULL` or something returned by previous `*alloc` functions.

Comment: m was returned previously by malloc(), so the use of realloc should be fine? Or has safe to be returned by a *alloc function?

Comment: If `safe2` is `NULL`, then calling `free(safe2)` makes no sense.

Comment: Anyway, your bug is that you're trying to `realloc` all of the rows using the new size of the matrix.  You need to use the old size, then set the new row pointers using `malloc`.  So you need to pass the old size to the function.  As it stands, you don't have enough information for it to work.

Comment: True, `free(safe2)` does not make sense there, but I had previous versions without this call that produced the same output.

Comment: Not in the line `double *safe2 = realloc(m[i], cols * sizeof(double));`, when `row` is bigger than the previous number of elements in `m`.

Comment: Luz, need to see how calling code initialized `m`.  Post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, the function needs the old and new dimensions to grow or shrink the memory allocations.
Do not free the temporary pointers used directly with `realloc` (`safe` and `safe2`). That is handled by `realloc`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double **free_matrix ( double **fm, int rows) {
    if ( fm) {
        while ( rows) {
            --rows;
            free ( fm[rows]);
        }
        free ( fm);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void matrix_show ( double **m, int rows, int cols) {
    for ( int r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {
        for ( int c = 0; c < cols; ++c) {
            printf ( "%6.1f ", m[r][c]);
        }
        printf ( "\n");
    }
}

double **matrix_resize ( double **m, int rows, int cols, int newrows, int newcols) {
    int i = 0;
    int temprows = 0;
    double **temp = NULL;
    double **safe = NULL;

    // shrinking - save pointers to free later
    if ( newrows < rows) {
        temprows = rows - newrows;
        if ( NULL != ( temp = malloc ( sizeof *temp * temprows))) {
            for ( int each = 0; each < temprows; ++each) {
                temp[each] = m[each + newrows];
            }
        } else {
            fprintf ( stderr, "problem malloc **temp");
            return m;
        }
    }
    if ( NULL == ( safe = realloc ( m, newrows * sizeof *m))) {
        fprintf ( stderr, "problem realloc safe");
        temp = free_matrix ( temp, temprows);
        return m;
    }
    m = safe;
    if ( rows < newrows) {
        int items = newrows - rows;
        for ( int each = 0; each < items; ++each) {
            m[each + rows] = NULL;
        }
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < newrows; ++i) {
        double *safe2 = realloc ( m[i], newcols * sizeof **m);
        if (safe2 == NULL) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "problem realloc safe2");
            temp = free_matrix ( temp, temprows);
            return m;
        }
        m[i] = safe2;
        if ( i >= rows) {
            // zero new row
            for ( int each = 0; each < newcols; ++each) {
                m[i][each] = 0;
            }
        } else {
            // zero new elements in row
            for ( int each = cols; each < newcols; ++each) {
                m[i][each] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    temp = free_matrix ( temp, temprows);
    return m;
}

int main ( void) {
    double **mat = NULL;
    int oldrw = 0;
    int rw = 4;
    int oldcl = 0;
    int cl = 4;

    // 4 x 4
    mat = matrix_resize ( mat, oldrw, oldcl, rw, cl);
    for ( int r = 0; r < rw; ++r) {
        for ( int c = 0; c < cl; ++c) {
            mat[r][c] = r * cl + c + 1;
        }
    }
    matrix_show ( mat, rw, cl);
    printf ( "\n");

    // 6 x 6
    oldrw = rw;
    rw = 6;
    oldcl = cl;
    cl = 6;
    mat = matrix_resize ( mat, oldrw, oldcl, rw, cl);
    matrix_show ( mat, rw, cl);
    printf ( "\n");

    // 7 x 3
    oldrw = rw;
    rw = 7;
    oldcl = cl;
    cl = 3;
    mat = matrix_resize ( mat, oldrw, oldcl, rw, cl);
    matrix_show ( mat, rw, cl);
    printf ( "\n");

    // 2 x 2
    oldrw = rw;
    rw = 2;
    oldcl = cl;
    cl = 2;
    mat = matrix_resize ( mat, oldrw, oldcl, rw, cl);
    matrix_show ( mat, rw, cl);

    mat = free_matrix ( mat, rw);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The pointers `safe` and `safe2` are temporary with respect to the OP's `matrix_resize` function, not with respect to `realloc`.  And of course it is the original pointers that are freed by `realloc`, if that turns out to be necessary, not `safe` and `safe2`.  The reason to avoid freeing those pointers is that they point to the (re)allocated space that the function is trying to provide, not that their cleanup is already assured by some means.

Answer (score 0):

Because of `realloc` may failed, I recommend to change the size of row and the size of column separately. So when `realloc` fail, you can deal with it properly. I wrote a function that can resize the row of matrix.

- If `m` is `NULL`, we simply return `calloc` instead of `realloc`.
- If `m` is not `NULL` and the `old_rows` is larger than `new_rows`, we store pointers that would be lost by `realloc` for further `free`.
- If `m` is not `NULL` and the `old_rows` is smaller or equal to `new_rows`, we just call `realloc` and initialize the new part of `m`.

Code:

```
double **matrix_rerow(double **m, int old_rows, int new_rows)
{
    if (!m)
        return calloc(new_rows,sizeof(*m));
    else if(old_rows > new_rows){
        const int len = old_rows - new_rows;
        double **save = malloc(sizeof(*save)*len);
        if (!save)
            return NULL;
        memcpy(save,m+new_rows,sizeof(*save)*len);
        m = realloc(m,sizeof(*m)*new_rows);
        if (!m){
            free(save);
            return NULL;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
            free(save[i]);
        free(save);
        return m;
    }else{
        m = realloc(m,sizeof(*m)*new_rows);
        if (!m)
            return NULL;
        memset(m+old_rows,0,sizeof(*m)*(new_rows-old_rows));
        return m;
    }
}
```

For changing size of column, there is `matrix_recol`. We use **pointer to `int`** instead of `int`. Because each row call `realloc` may fail. When it fails, caller can observe `row` to check how many rows have been modified correctly.

```
double** matrix_recol(double **m, int *rows, int cols)
{
    const int save = *rows;
    *rows = 0;
    if (!m){
        m = matrix_rerow(NULL, 0, *rows);
        if (!m)
            return NULL;
        for(int i = 0; i < save; ++i,(*rows)++){
            void *ptr = realloc(m[i],sizeof(**m)*cols);
            if (!ptr){
                free(m);
                return NULL;
            }
            m[i] = ptr;
        }
        return m;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < save; ++i,(*rows)++){
        void *ptr = realloc(m[i],sizeof(**m)*cols);
        if (!ptr)
            return NULL;
        m[i] = ptr;
    }
    return m;
}
```